# save TimeZone into separate column in db?

Tags: java, mysql

i have a table. i need to save date and timezone separately. because users are provided with dropdown of different timezones. now i need to selected date and timezone separately into separate columns? Please suggest me how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for replying. i want to save timezone information in a separate column. Please advice in which format it should be saved and what can be the datatype of the column?Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save timezone information in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790017/how-to-save-timezone-information-in-database)

Comment: So what's wrong with my answer to your previous identical question?

Answer (score 0):

Store the date as a `datetime` field, and use [UTC dates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-date). Then, you can use the [`convert_tz`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function to convert based on the varchar timezone code.